# What is the reason to implement authorization on app engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am trying a sample app for Android with endpoints. As far as I understand, we supposed to implement authorization (as below code) for each method on google app engine.

```
/**
 * Provides the ability to insert a new Score entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "scores.insert")
public Score insert(Score score, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
  ...
}
```

I want to understand (as a beginner), if I don't implement this kind of authorization to methods can anybody mess with my backend app? Can they access the datastore and see the database or access the information stored on datastore with a query? What kind of security flaw will it cause? **So that I can understand for which methods should I implement authorization.**

One more point is Index.html which, I think, I don't need. App engine automatically create this but I want to run this app only on Android. **Can I just delete it or should I?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to identify an user you should add `User` param to the method's parameters list. If logic of the method returns the same results for any user there's no need for user authentication, but this way you allows everyone to call your method without any authentication.

There's no possibility to access database or query database if you design your endpoints well. Just restrict what is returned by endpoint methods.

> One more point is Index.html which, I think, I don't need. App engine
>   automatically create this but I want to run this app only on Android.
>   Can I just delete it or should I?

If it still compiles and runs on backend why not. index.html is displayed when you open your app in browser e.g. https://appname.appspot.com. You can always provide empty file if you don't want to show anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what about the servlets like to get blob upload url? Because I can just activate them with web browser and the link. Is this a security problem?

Comment: You can also call any endpoint method using browser or curl or wget utilities. If you design it well it's not security problem at all. For example downloading some premium content from within the app may be implemented like this: call endpoint method (oauth protected) to obtain unique identifier to the premium resource, check if user has rights to download the content, then call the method to download blob using this identifier. This way only eligible users will be able to download premium content.